# Ищу курсы по Мадженто

Tags: magento

Ищу курсы по Мадженто, желательно бесплатные, язык предпочтительно русский, но можно и на инглише, заранее спасибо.

Comment: @e13, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Если кому нужно, нашел на хабре курс видеолекций, только на английском, курсе и описание по ссылке: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142298/, сам пока только начал смотреть, так что подробней рассказать не могу.

Comment: Вопрос не по теме, поиск видеокурсов — оффтопик.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, что вспомнили об этом спустя 3 года :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Вопрос всплыл из-за спам-ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Для понимания Magento обязателен к просмотру курс Fundamentals of Magento Development: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4027861

Его ведет читатет один из разработчиков Magento. Раньше он был вообще в платном доступе (около 1000 уе).

Comment: Спасибо, я уже нашел кучу книг и полезных ресурсов, правда все они на английском. Так что инфы теперь хватает, нужно только учить. Кстати очень хорошо изложена инфа в книгах и ресурсах для подготовки к сертификации, от основ и самой структуры до написания кода.